# What is the difference between getTimeInMilis() and .getTime().getTime()?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a Calendar object c. What will be the result of this lines:

```
c.getTimeInMilis();
```

and

```
c.getTime().getTime();
```

Comment: Since this is just a one-liner, I suggest you compile and run the code and see what happens.

Comment: The result will be a bunch of calculations by the CPU + a temporary object in memory which gets garbage collected since it is unused. The difference is in the amount of CPU calculations and temporary in a different call stack. There is no difference in output, since there is no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ostensibly they are identical.

But I'd plump for the first one since it does not create (explicitly) a `java.util.Date` temporary.

`c.getTimeInMilis();` is also more descriptive.

Personally I dislike "chained" functions statements in Java (i.e. things like `a.b().c().d();`) since they tend to be where `NullPointerException` possibilities tend to lurk.

Comment: It means that getTimeInMillis() is more memory efficient?

Comment: That is indeed a possibility. A literal interpretation would burden the garbage collector with having to delete a `java.util.Date`. Perhaps though a java compiler is allowed to optimise out the temporary. I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Right from the Oracle's [calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) API

[`getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime())

> Returns a Date object representing this Calendar's time value
>   (millisecond offset from the Epoch").

```
   // create a calendar
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

   // print current time
   System.out.println(" Current time is : " + cal.getTime());
```

**prints**  *Current time is : Wed Jun 01 08:51:58 EDT 2016*

[`getTimeInMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis())

> Returns this Calendar's time value in milliseconds.

```
   // create a calendar
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

   // print current time in milliseconds
   System.out.println("Current time is : " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

**prints** *Current time is : 1464785518706*

Comment: And now ... is that identical or different?

Comment: With the edit you prove that the output is different.

Comment: `+ cal.getTime()` will "stringify" the date object. You need another `cal.getTime().getTime()`

Comment: @Thomas as other answer suggests "Ostensibly they are identical.". you can debate on what "ostensibly" means here.

Answer (score 1):

From `Calendar.java`.

```
public final Date getTime() {
    return new Date(getTimeInMillis());
}
```

`getTime()` uses `getTimeInMillis()` to return a `Date` object so they're essentially the same. <strike>Obviously</strike> Probably `getTimeInMillis()` will be faster than `getTime().getTime()`.

Comment: "Obviously getTimeInMillis() will be faster than getTime().getTime()." not sure about that. The JLS doesn't mandate that. Or does it? If so then lunch is on me. Perhaps a particular JVM has a poor implementation of one of the two versions.

Comment: But shouldn't just calling a function be faster than creating an object and then calling another function on it? Just asking.

Comment: It *ought* to be but I have reservations about calling that *obvious*.

Comment: But one more thing: "getTime() uses getTimeInMillis() to return a Date object". Is that mandated by the JLS or merely happens to be the case on your implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The Java source is available.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.getTime%28%29

Calendar.getTime():

```
public final Date getTime() {
    return new Date(getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Calendar.getTimeInMillis():

```
public long getTimeInMillis() {
    if (!isTimeSet) {
        updateTime();
    }
    return time;
}
```

So `myCalendar.getTime()` is just a short cut for `new Date(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis())`.

... and `myCalendar.getTime().getTime()` is a shortcut for (deep breath!) :

```
new Date(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis()).getTime();
```

... which is a long and inefficient way of getting that same `long`.